# Robot exploding when touching other objects

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everyone!

I am having problems with my simulation. When my robot tries to move over an object (in this case the parking block) it suddenly explodes (see picture) [image: image description]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I am using Gazebo version 1.8.6.

EDIT: I also have a Plugin, where I set the angular and linear velocity of the model.
sdf file: [model2.sdf](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/13813905804166631.sdf)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4589/robot-exploding-when-touching-other-objects/) by [atenea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/403/atenea/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-10-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-10-04**:
Can you please post your robot's SDF file, and also indicate what version of Gazebo you're using?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-10-10**:
I'll also need the DAE files please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Make sure that your collision objects, inertial parameters, and joints are all correct.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2020-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0